# Can you invoke a method via reflection on behalf of another class

Tags: java, reflection

I have a client.class that uses Util.class to invoke a method on target.class.  The invocation is forced by calling the setAccessible(true) to the method of target.class.

**Question:** Is there a way to have this Util.class determine if the client.class has access to this particular method of target.class?

I want to skip having to use the method setAccessible(true).  client.class has access to the method I am invoking in target.class, but Util.class does not have access because the method is protected or default.

Comment: Why do you not want to use setAccessible? Reflection already breaks the rules anyway.

Comment: The code is being flagged, so we want to at most allow only if the client.class has access.

Comment: Just catch and handle `IllegalAccessException` and rethrow as whatever exception you want to the client code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to establish whether the client class had access to the method by examining the packages, inheritance chain, and accessibility of the method. Take a look at the [`MethodModifierSpy` class in the Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodModifiers.html).

But even if the client class had access, your code in `Util` would still need to call `setAccessible(true)` when `Util` does not have access, since the reflection code is part of `Util`, not the client class.

Comment: I could use your tip to determine access, thanks.  I think what I ultimately want is not possible, since it will only be another form of impersonation being worked around by reflection setAccessible(true).