# Reusing Class state to invoke the same method via Java reflection

Tags: java, reflection, migration

I am using Java reflection to invoke a method in a remote server from a local application. As part of the request to invoke the method, I am also sending the state of the Class object, which contains the value of the variables that are modified by the method during runtime, such that when the method is invoked remotely and the application gets the result from the server, the variables which were modified can be updated in my local application.

Client

```
public MyClass {

double var1;
...


public long dotest(){
  Method toExecute;
  Class<?>[] paramTypes = null;
  Object[] paramValues = null;
  Long result = null;
        try{
          /*
          * Method specifications are stored and sent in a Class called MyPack to the server
          */
          toExecute = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("localdotest", paramTypes);
          Vector results = getCloudController().execute(toExecute,paramValues,this,this.getClass());
  if(results != null){
        result = (Long)results.get(0);
           copyState(results.get(1));
  }else{
           result = localdotest();
  }
  } catch (SecurityException se){
  } catch (NoSuchMethodException ns){
  } catch (Throwable th){
  } 
return result;

}

public void copyState(Object state){
   MyClass
   localstate = (MyClass) state;
   this.var1 = localstate.var1;
}
```

Server

```
 myPack = (Pack) ois.readObject();
 functionName = myPack.getfunctionName();
 paramTypes = myPack.getparamTypes();
 paramValues = myPack.getparamValues();
 state = myPack.getstate();
 stateDType = myPack.getstateType();

 try {
   Class cls = Class.forName(stateDType.getName());
   Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod(functionName, paramTypes);
   try{
        Object result = method.invoke(state, paramValues);
        ResultPack rp = new ResultPack(result, state);
        oos.writeObject(rp);
        oos.flush();
   } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
      returnnull(oos);
   } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
      returnnull(oos);
  } catch(Exception ex){
  ResultPack rp = new ResultPack(null, state);
  oos.writeObject(rp);
  oos.flush();
  }
```

However, I have notice that the state of the Class sent is always the same when the method is invoked remotely. So, I am planning to cache the state of the class in the server. The goal is to avoid sending the same state every time the method is invoked.

So far, I don't see any problem to do so. I tried to find something related, and these links [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333896/invoking-a-method-via-reflection-with-generics-and-overrides), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468373/can-you-invoke-a-method-via-reflection-on-behalf-of-another-class) are the most closer topics I found, but still I cannot get off this "itch" from my mind. Could somebody please point me out if there is any potential drawback to adopt such strategy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I am using Java reflection to invoke a method in a remote server from a local application`. Either badly worded or simply untrue. Show some code.

Comment: Sorry but I can’t see how your linked questions have anything to do with your question. One of them is not even related to Java. All in all you seem to describe a network/RMI problem that is not related to Reflection at all. Though it’s badly worded as [nablex already pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522624/reusing-class-state-to-invoke-the-same-method-via-java-reflection#comment39845772_25522624).

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I added some code. Maybe the explanation is not that clear. The system works. I am not looking for technical support, I just want to know if some of the data which I am sending can be cache in the server.

Comment: It depends on what makes up the “state of the Class object” you are talking about. For arbitrary objects (object graphs) it’s very hard to determine whether they have changed. If the entire state is `Serializable` you can compare the serialized forms though. But then, why are you reinventing RMI?

Comment: I am trying to get a lighter RMI, which does not need to send duplicated information.